# Waiting for state update

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing a shopping cart in React.js and I need to wait for a state to finish updating so I can send its value to a backend database. I have a *quantState* variable, which stores the quantity of items of a determined product in the cart. When I click 'increase', *quantState* must increase by one unit. If I have 10 units, when I click *increase*, it should update to 11 and then send it to the backend, but what actually happens is that 10 is sent to the backend and then it finishes updating to 11. If I click again, it sends the value of 11 before updating and so on . How can I wait for the state to finish updating before sending it to the backend ? Here's the increase function:

```
const increase = async (id) => {
        shopCart.forEach(async (el, i) => {
            if (el.id === id) {
                await setQuantState(prev => prev + 1);
                await updateCart(); // sends the updated values of the cart to the backend 
            }
        }
        )
    }
```

Comment: If your state handling is based on `useState()` then it would be natural to respond to state changes by using `useEffect()`. Alternatively you could switch to a `useState()` extension that supports callbacks. Both approaches are described here: [React useState with Callback](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback)

Comment: Thanks, friend. I solved the problem with the useEffect dependency array. I was unsure if that was the  preferred way of solving this.